# Ejected Create react app jest coverage report not accurate

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I create an app using create-react-app and after that I ejected it. Currently doing my test suite, I want to show my test coverage so I added "collectCoverage" : true under my package.json. After I run my test it doesnt show the percentage of my test coverage

[image]

Is there anything I need to do?

Here is the Links.test.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";

import Links from "./Links";

it("should show correct links", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<Links />);

  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Below is the Links component that was being tested

```
import React from "react";

const Links = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container mb-4 mt-4" id="Links">
      <div className="h4 mb-3">OUR LINKS</div>
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap mw-90">
        <a
          href="https://site.ca/sites.aspx"
          target="_blank"
          className="buttonImage siteImage"
        >
          <div className="darkenBackground d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
            <div className="text-center h4">My Site</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" className="buttonImage mapsImage">
          <div className="darkenBackground d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
            <div className="text-center h4">Maps</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" className="buttonImage loopImage">
          <div className="darkenBackground d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
            <div className="text-center h4">Social</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" className="buttonImage polcyImage">
          <div className="darkenBackground d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
            <div className="text-center h4">
              Acceptable Use <br /> and Security Policies
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Links;
```

Comment: What does your test look like?

Comment: its a snapshot for now, doesn't it considered as test coverage?

Comment: Yes it should. How about the Link component? And the snapshot for good measure.

Comment: Link component is pretty basic

Comment: Any idea whats wrong @TomErikStøwer?

Comment: I added your component and test to a clean CRA project, and I'm getting normal coverage output. Not sure what else I can do to help. If you're able to provide a minimal case where this can be reproduced, like a repo that can be cloned, maybe it's possible to see what's wrong.